# What does the term 'spare habit' mean exactly?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Example in Usage:

> July 20, 1890. Consulted by Mrs., 50, spare habit, dark hair and eyes, nervous temperament, neurotic family history;...

Comment: Presumably, it isn't a nun's extra change of clothing. :)

Comment: In older Danish, Habit is a suit

Comment: It means a bit skinny

Answer (score 24):

*Spare habit* here means thin body.

[A DICTIONARY OF ENGLISH PHILOSOPHICAL TERMS](http://www.e-torredebabel.com/philosophydictionary/habit-philosophyglossary.htm) - Francis Garden - 1878

> In physical and medical science, the word is used in its original
>   largeness of meaning, i. e. not as confined to action, but as
>   embracing states, modes of being, and we are accordingly familiar with
>   the phrases "habit of body," "a full" or "a spare habit."

So habit can be used to refer to the body. For further clarification, we can consult:

[HABIT IN THE ENGLISH NOVEL](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LqREAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22spare%20habit%22%20meaning&source=bl&ots=i_IEKKZofF&sig=XlcNeNT_yGNcOjJqzE0-YSg01bc&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22spare%20habit%22%20meaning&f=false), 1850-1900: Lived Environments, Practices of the Self.

> Outward form or general appearance is a
>   'habit'... I may be of a spare habit whereas my friend is inclined to
>   corpulence.

The author is contrasting corpulence with spare habit here.

If we consult a dictionary for the word corpulence, we discover it means:

> The state of being fat; obesity.

-- [O.L.D](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/corpulence)

Comment: The related term *habitus* is still in current use in the medical context (I'm a doctor).

Answer (score 16):

*[Spare](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spare)* means ***thin, with no excess fat*** and *[habit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/habit)* means ***constitution***.

> I may be of a spare habit whereas my friend is inclined to corpulence

[Habit in the English Novel, 1850-1900: Lived Environments, Practices of the Self](https://books.google.com/books?id=LqREAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=%22spare%20habit%22&source=bl&ots=i_IEKKZkjI&sig=id9Qw5ZTVXM27bSY1J12VTJTVTU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivrZeCy_HTAhVpDMAKHVz-CE4Q6AEIQDAH#v=onepage&q=%22spare%20habit%22&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

Combining some of the dictionary entries, I deduce this means: "of a thin body"

"In physical and medical science, the word is used in its original largeness of meaning, i. e. not as confined to action, but as embracing states, modes of being, and we are accordingly familiar with the phrases "habit of body," "a full" or "a spare habit." Also, medical men speak of a cachexy, a permanent bad condition of the body."

http://www.e-torredebabel.com/philosophydictionary/habit-philosophyglossary.htm

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spare